# Ckeditor edit bar position with symfony CMF

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, symfony-cmf

I have installed Ckeditor in my project Symphony CMF to allow editing the content of the pages inline. I have a toolbar in the top of the page with edit/save button to make changes.
Everything works fine, except that this toolbar is hiding some of the page's content.

Is there a way to change its position or resize it to the top-right corner ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

what i did in a project with a similar issue is that i add a class to the  when editing is enabled and have a css to add some extra margin to my header when the class is present.

Comment: I was hoping i could change the position of the editing bar, but your solution can help, thank you

Comment: Thank you again for your solution, it works, but now my header bar for which i gave some extra margin is hiding the notification i get from the ckeditor when i save the changes

Comment: Its all "just" CSS. look at the html you see and change settings for .create-ui-toolbar-wrapper and .create-ui-logo in your custom css, then load that after the createjs css files.

Comment: It works fine now, I used the z-index to order elements display. Thank you